# webview going blank upon double tapping on password field of html page on Android Tablet

Tags: android-webview

Issue: webview is going blank upon double tapping on password field of html page on Android Tablet. Just typing user name and password on the html page has no problem.

Tested on: Samsung Galaxy tablet (GT-P7510) and Motorola Xoom

layout file snippet:

> 

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_xlarge_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dip"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/urlview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test"                 
            />
                <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  
                />                       

        </LinearLayout>     

        <WebView 
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code to setup webview:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
setUserAgent(getString(R.string.user_agent_suffix));
```

Other:

Adding support for zoom on webview or setting up touch and focus listener did not help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and considered using an ugly html trick by simulating the password input with 2 text input:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<input type="text" id="hiddenPwd" onkeyup="$('#fakePwd')[0].value = '*************'.substr(0, $('#hiddenPwd')[0].value.length);" /> 
<div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"><input type="text" id="fakePwd" onfocus="$('#hiddenPwd')[0].focus();"/></div>
</div>
```

Works nicely, the only drawback is that the cursor is not showing...

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems in my application. Seems what bug affects all Honeycomb tablets.

The problem goes away, if you turn on hardware acceleration. But hardware accelerated WebView has problem with performance and transparency.

For me works fine software rendered WebView on hardware accelerated window:

```
mWindow.setFlags(
    Window.LayoutParam.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
    Window.LayoutParam.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
...
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE);
```

PS: Of course you can also enable hardware acceleration for entire application in your manifest file.